# Is there a way to ignore RewriteRule if the script executing is a PHP script on the server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule intended to route the users to my `index.php` if they visit my `/images/*` directory so that I can route this correctly and check user permissions before displaying the image.

However, the issue here is that when I try to display the image to the user, the call to display the image is being picked up by the RewriteRule too.

Is there a way to ignore the RewriteRule if the file executing is PHP/phtml?

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (/)?images/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm looking for something like

```
if the file executing is not a PHP script/being called from the server:
    RewriteRule (/)?images/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think you should always redirect to the image/index.php from where you can check user is authenticated or not, If user is authorized then display that image URL.

Comment: But wouldn't a re-write rule then redirect the image back to image/index.php when they passed authorization and I tried to display it to them? That's the issue I'm having currently, however rather than image/index.php I'm just doing it in /index.php @HarshSanghani

Comment: No you can take image name form the query string

Comment: `RewriteRule (/)?images/(.*)$ /images/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]` would this not create an infinite loop, though? @HarshSanghani

Comment: can you please try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RewriteCond` to check if current request is not for `.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (/)?images/(.+)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I feel like it's my bad for explaining it poorly, my issue is that, although I'm currently redirecting image/ urls to index.php, whenever I try to display the image in the browser (from the website, the idea behind this is to prevent a user from being able to directly view an image) then it routes again.

I hope to perform permission checks (in PHP) in my Images controller before displaying the image, which requires the initial rewrite, however that comes back to bite me when - should the user pass the permission check - I try to display the image to them.

Comment: I wish to ignore the mod_write check if the request came from a PHP file on my server, that's probably a better way of wording it.

Comment: Is your php file sending HTTP request to your webserver? php should just be doing file I/O for rendering image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :-

.htaccess code :-

```
RewriteRule (/)?images/authorize/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,QSA]  // Change path or name according to you
RewriteRule (/)?images/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PHP code :-

check for user authorization.

```
if ($user) // Authorized
{
  redirect ('http://project_name/image/authorize/test.jpg'); //// Change path or name according to you
} else {
echo 'Not Authorized';
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: Oh, I see - I've already got to this point though, my /images/ directory is routing through the controller, it's just when the browser tries to render the image once they pass authorization it then tries to route again because the rewriterule is being hit on that render.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this shouldn't now be routing on the 'images/authorize' url beacause it seems to be doing that, `'Route images/authorize/40167/RdHvNqt.jpg does not exist'`

Comment: @Jackhardcastle is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too proficient in url rewrites. but i think you might want to try using 2 `REWRITE_COND` directives. one for the checking the IP of requester, and the other for the file types.

[this might be useful](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

"REMOTE_ADDR
The IP address of the remote host (see the mod_remoteip module)."

so what i am saying is, maybe you can check the IP and allow the IP of your own webserver(first `cond`) to access the images(for this you need the second `cond`). and you should be good to go.